# Most efficient way to iterate through three values, in multiple loops environment

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, binary, char

I have this struct which represents a pixel with its **three 8-bits blocks R, G, B** :

```
typedef struct pixel_st {
    uint8_t r, g, b;
} pixel_t;

pixel_t *array_of_pixels; // array of pixels
```

**Question is**, given an array with an enormous amount of pixels, what would be **the most efficient way to iterate through R, G, and B and remove their last bit, in loops that iterate through a file, and through its characters' bits**.

The question may be not clear so, in code this is basically what I want to do :

```
For each character in file {
    For each bit in character (its 7 last bits) {
        change next color r, g or b of current pixel, 
        if all colors of pixel have been changed 
            go to next pixel
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried :

```
// iterators
char ch; // text file characters
pixel_t *pixel_iterator = array_of_pixels; // image pixels
uint8_t *r, *g, *b, i; // pixel colors
char last = ' ';

while((ch = getc(f)) != EOF) { // iterate through characters
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // character size in ASCII
    if(last == 'b' || last == ' ') { // first iteration, or last was b => go to r
      if(last == 'b') { // go to next pixel
        pixel_iterator++;
      }
      r = pixel_iterator->r >> 1;
      r << 1;
      last = 'r';
    } else if(last == 'r') { // go to g
      g = pixel_iterator->r >> 1;
      g << 1;
      last = 'g';
    } else if(last == 'g') { // go to b
      b = pixel_iterator->r >> 1;
      b << 1;
      last = 'b';
    }
  }
}
```

This looks not efficient at all. I would like to do it in a few lines if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm addressing two points in your question - iteration speed and where you said "remove the last bit".

The first point - look into "union".  A union allows you to overlay a struct but treat it as a different memory layout.  In your specific situation, you can treat the 3x8-bit values as a single 24-bit value.

Then you're reading 3 bytes at a time.

When you start thinking of things as a single 24-bit value, it's very easy to remove the "last" bit...some pseudocode:

```
char[3] bytes = {}

long v = bytes[0]<<16 | bytes[1] << 8 | bytes[2]
long out = v & 0b111111101111111011111110
bytes[0] = out >> 16
bytes[1] = out >> 8
bytes[2] = out
```

Note - this is *pseudocode* --- please no syntax critiques :)

@paul - I hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !